I need to drive 4 12v dc encoder motors from one controller
In addition to the motors, there are two momentary button switches for each, and an N/O limit  switch.  Each Motor is twelve feet from the controller. I plan to run a 10 conductor 22 ga cable to connect each.
My question is can either an ARM Cortex or ESP32 deal with signals traveling that distance in terms of timing and distance given the tiny current involved?
